# How do I program this thing (extract data from other website)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a union member of a airlines company, and I possess the elementary level of HTML, PHP and MYSQL. I have experience programming a library system and personnel system.

Our union would like to create an online platform, one of the function is to allow our crews to calculate their flying allowances and salary easily.

I think first of all, I need the roster data, so the platform is required to log in my company website in order to extract the roster data, and then I can code with PHP.

Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to write PHP code "log in to my company website and extract the data".

Or what is the best language for this program you recommend? Maybe I can learn a new language if PHP is not applicable.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: First, check to see if your company website offers an API to access the roster.  That would be a far better solution.  If it does not, then consider programming that *first*, then you can access the data via the API, rather than attempting to "scrape" the data from the pages.

Comment: If the information you're dealing with is sensitive be very careful and consider using a professional, at least for advice. A beginner doing PHP/SQL is likely to leave a lot of data security holes.

Comment: I've already written a library in PHP to do this. Hopefully it will help you out: http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/11/01/a-highly-flexible-php-web-crawler-library/

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will go check out the API and the PHP provided by Pamblam is really helpful :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

To answer your question, Yes, you can write this in PHP. And by you, I mean you! None of us know the site and there is no way for us to know how it operates.

You may want to consider if there is an API for this site. You may want to load the site via cURL or another HTTP request into PHP and parse the HTML. There are a lot of ways to do this.

PHP is not the only language to perform this in: ASP.NET, Perl, Python... in the end, it sounds like you need to collect data that you would normally see using a web browser, so you're going to mimic that behavior with whatever language you choose to use.